# Python loop through two dataframes and find similar column

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I am currently working on a project where my goal is to get the game scores for each NCAA mens basketball game. In order to do this, I need to use the python package sportsreference. I need to use two dataframes, one called df which has the game date and one called box_index (shown below) which has the unique link of each game. I need to get the date column replaced by the unique link of each game. These unique links start with the date (formatted exactly as in the date column of df), which makes it easier to do this with regex or the .contains(). I keep getting a Keyerror: 0 error. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my logic below?

```
from sportsreference.ncaab.schedule import Schedule

                   
def get_team_schedule(name):
    combined =Schedule(name).dataframe  
    box_index = combined["boxscore_index"]
    box = box_index.to_frame()
    #print(box)
    for i in range(len(df)):
        for j in range(len(box)):
            if box.loc[i,"boxscore_index"].contains(df.loc[i, "date"]):
                df.loc[i,"date"] = box.loc[i,"boxscore_index"]
    

get_team_schedule("Virginia")
```

Comment: can you chare a few rows of what `df` looks like. It's hard to understand what you are ultimately doing without it

Comment: "one called df which has the game date", did you mean "game data" and "not game date"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like "box" and "df" are pandas data frame, and since you are iterating through all the rows, it may be more efficient to use `iterrows` (instead of searching by index with ".loc")

```
for i, row_df in df.iterrows():
    for j, row_box in box.iterrows():
        if row_box["boxscore_index"].contains(row_df["date"]):
            df.at[i, 'date'] = row_box["boxscore_index"]
```

the ".at" function will overwrite the value at a given cell

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi, iterrows is more efficient than `.loc.`, however itertuples is about 10x faster, and zip about 100xs.

The `Keyerror: 0 error` is saying you can't get that row at index 0, because there is no index value of 0 using `box.loc[i,"boxscore_index"]` (the index values are the dates, for example `'2020-12-22-14-virginia'`). You could use `.iloc.` though, like `box.iloc[i]["boxscore_index"]`. You'd have to convert all the `.loc` to that.

Like the other post said though, I wouldn't go that path. I actually wouldn't even use iterrows here. I would put the box_index into a list, then iterarte through that. Then use pandas to filter your `df` dataframe. I'm sort of making some assumptions of what `df` looks like, so if this doesn't work, or not what you looking to do, please share some sample rows of `df`:

```
from sportsreference.ncaab.schedule import Schedule
                   
def get_team_schedule(name):
    combined = Schedule(name).dataframe  
    box_index_list = list(combined["boxscore_index"])
    for box_index in box_index_list:
        temp_game_data = df[df["date"] == boxscore_index]
        print(box_index)
        print(temp_game_data,'\n')

get_team_schedule("Virginia")
```